# copy constructor on base class

Tags: c++, copy, move

List C.67 in the cpp core guideline says: A base class should suppress copying, and provide a virtual clone instead if "copying" is desired.

If the copy constructor is defined as deleted in the base, then the move operations are also suppressed for base class and all derived classes.

On the other hand, move operations may improve performance.  My question is what would be realistic approach we should adopt when we design a class hierarchy?

Suppose we have the following class hierarchy? how should we design A and B to properly support copy and move operations.

```
class A{
public:
  A(const std::string& as) = deleted;
  //should we define other copy/move operators?

  virtual void foo();//
  virtual ~A();//

private:
  std::string s;
};

class B: public A{
public:
  //how do we define copy/move operators?

  void foo() override;
  ~B() override;
private:
  std::vector<std::string> vs;
};
```

Comment: This is the same problem you run into with the copy constructor. If you only have a `Base *` how will you know which derived class to move? Add the constructors back in to the derived classes if you have a good case to do so.

Comment: What "class hierarchy"?

Answer (score 0):

## Confusions

### Copy *vs.* clone

First, note that `clone` is not “copy for objects of polymorphic type”: they are simply different operations with different semantics.

- Copy (via a copy constructor) means “create an object of **statically specified** type with the *value* of another”.  (Recall that constructors cannot be `virtual`, for want of a *current object* whose class could provide the behavior.)  The user *must* specify the type, and should expect that the copied object is “reinterpreted” (sliced) as the *known*, specified type if it is in fact of a derived type.
- `clone` copies an object of a **dynamically known** derived class as another object of *that* class.  Since the argument determines the type of the result, the user *cannot* specify it and indeed does not (statically) know what is chosen.  (Heap allocation is a corollary.)

Which one you want depends on what lifetime and type you want the result to have (including “the same type as that one” as a choice).  I find it puzzling that someone would write a copy (*e.g.*, a by-value parameter whose **specified** type is a concrete base class) and be surprised by what they had chosen.

### Virtual assignment

Next, note that an abstract class need not fear slicing except on assignment (which must be via a reference).  Assignment can be `virtual` (since an object already exists), but it can’t statically avoid slicing because the types need not match:

```
struct B {
  virtual ~B()=default;
  virtual B& operator=(const B&)=default;
  // ...
};
struct D1 : B {
  D& operator=(const B&) override;
  // ...
};
struct D2 : B {/* ... */};

void f() {
  B &&b=D1();
  b=D2();  // ok
}
```

The assignment must use just the common `B` part, or… throw?  If the assignment can fail, it’d be clearer to provide it as a function: perhaps `bool assign_like(const B&) &;` that returns `false` if the types differ.

## Protection

So we indeed must do something about at least assignment if we want to avoid the risk of slicing.  The Core Guidelines idea of deleting the assignment operator is reasonable, but I would just make it `protected` in each abstract base class.

### Concrete leaves only

If you never inherit from a concrete class, that’s all you need to prevent slicing: the implicit (`public`) special member functions in the leaf classes **do not slice**, automatically use the base’s corresponding SMFs, and can in turn be used automatically as appropriate.  (For example, the concrete classes may then be passed by value.)

### “Deep” hierarchy

In a concrete base class, you have two choices for each SMF:

1. Make it `protected` anyway, **denying** the possibility of deliberately copying an object (even if the source’s complete object type is known statically).
2. Leave it available and send any confused users of the class hierarchy here to learn about the difference between copy and `clone` (and the impossibility of a “fully `virtual`” assignment).